# CSS3 only dropdown menu with transitions

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a CSS3 only dropdown menu with transitions but it's not working 100% as I would like it to. I want the underline hover state to be the same even when you hover over the expanding dropdown menu.

Here's my first try:
http://codepen.io/Winterfox/pen/wGmEbY

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
  li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    &:hover {
      .submenu {
        height: 85px;
      }
    }
    .submenu {
      overflow:hidden;
      position:absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #3862a0;
      height: 0;
      margin-top: 10px;
      line-height: 40px;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      transition:height 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition-delay: 0.1s;
      a {
        color: #fff;
        margin-top: 20px;
        font-size: 16px;
        &:hover {
          color: #fff;
          text-decoration:underline;
        }
      }
    }
    a {
      color: #999;
      display: block;
      padding: 0 7px 0 7px;
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
      &:hover {
        color: #3862a0;
        &::before {
          visibility: visible;
          transform: scale(1, 1);
        }
      }
      &::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: #3862a0;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transform: scale(0, 0);
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the hover state is removed when hovering the expanded dropdown menu. I tried to fix this by moving the transitions to the li element as shown here:
http://codepen.io/Winterfox/pen/ZWxqvp

But then I got the problem that 1# when changing the position on the hover state the dropdown doesn't look good when it closes again. 2# The blue underline for the menu text now shows at the bottom of the page.

Any suggestions how to fix this with CSS3 only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your thought was going in the right direction but instead of applying the styles to the `li` you could just move the anchor inside the `li:hover` block, as in:

```
li {
    ...
    &:hover {
        ...
        a {        
            color: #3862a0;
            &::before {
                visibility: visible;
                transform: scale(1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaxrwE